# create Directory in existing directory PHP

Tags: php

I'm a beginner with PHP I tried to create a form to create a folder, delete files and upload files.

I have created a directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\U_7\uploads\user1` what i want now is every folder the user will create be created in user1.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work and I don't know where the problem is.

---

dropbox.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$users=array("user1","user2");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    if(in_array($user,$users)){
        $_SESSION['user']=$user;
        echo ' <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <div>
       <form action="CreateFolder.php" method="post">
           <h2>
               Create New Folder
           </h2>
           <input name="createfolder" type="text">
           <input type="submit" value="Create Folder">
       </form>
       <form action="Delet file.php" method="post">
           <h2>
               Delete file
           </h2>
           <input name="Delete File" type="text">
           <input type="submit" value="Delete File">
       </form>
       <form action="Upload.php" method="post">
           <h2>
              Upload File
           </h2>
           <input type="file" value="Upload">
       </form>
    </div>
       </body>
       </html>';
```

createFolder.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$output_dir='\uploads\user1';

            $folder_name=$_POST['createfolder'];
            echo $output_dir.'\\'.$folder_name;
            if  (!is_dir($output_dir.'\\'.'$folder_name'))/* Check folder exists or not */
            {
                mkdir($output_dir.'\\'.$folder_name, 0777,true);/* Create folder by using mkdir function */
                echo "Folder Created";/* Success Message */
            }
            ?>
```

The output is just the directory:
\uploads\user1\Ahmed as Ahmed is the created folder by the user i Just print the directory to know how it looks like.

```
 echo $output_dir.'\\'.$folder_name;
```

is_dir function should return true and if statment should be excuted but thats not happened and the new directory hasnt been created.

---

Comment: Edit your question and update the code rather than putting it into comments `:-)`

Comment: why are you using \ and not /?

Comment: i dont  know if that make a difference i think one should use \ when writing a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the following line:

```
if  (!is_dir($output_dir.'\\'.'$folder_name'))
```

By

```
if  (!is_dir($output_dir.'\\'.$folder_name))
```

The single quotes surrounding the `$folder_name` variable are the issue. Variable replacements by its value do not happen if surrounded by single quotes.

You could also surround them by double quoutes, that is also valid and the variable gets replaced by its value:

```
if  (!is_dir($output_dir.'\\'."$folder_name"))
```

Comment: Then the issue is that the $output dir must be an absolute path. I don't know your source code tree, but you could try replacing the output dir initialisation by this: $output_dir=__DIR__ . '\uploads\user1';